# How to change the default gesture behavior in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, events, gesture

I have an element that appears from the right side of the screen when a button is clicked (something similar to many navigations). I want to add new ways to close it, especially on mobile. On a mobile device, it covers the whole screen (+ you can scroll it vertically). I'd like to change the default "go to the previous page" android gesture to hide the div (when you swipe from the sides of the screen). So if the div is visible (has a certain class), I'd like to remove that class and prevent the browser from going back to the previous page.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 27){
        console.log("There's no going back");
    }
});
```

Something like this (escape button click - console log), but with the right event. The code for removing the class isn't a problem (I put a console log in this example to simplify things), but I have no idea if there even is an event for what I'm trying to do. I've been searching for it, but to no avail.
I don't want to do a custom swipe with calculating the user input, position, etc. I don't think it would be 100% perfect, so I'm trying to use the correct event for that specific android (and possibly IOS) gesture.

Comment: Just a note that not everybody uses gesture navigation in Android, some people use 3-button style with a dedicated back button. In such case Android doesn't react to swipes

Comment: I know that, but it doesn't change the fact that it could be useful. I've managed to do a custom swipe (not a replacement for the android one, but better than nothing I guess). If someone knows the solution, I'd still be happy to see it.